# Bimodule structure $(R/I,R)$ of $R/I$ for two-sided ideal $I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital ring, and let $I \triangleleft R$ be a two-sided ideal in $R$. We can form the bimodule-structure $(R/I,R)$ on $R/I$. Am I correct in that the right-action $$R/I \times R \to R/I$$ here becomes $$(r+I) \cdot r' = (r+I) q(r') = (r+I)(r'+I) = (rr'+I)$$ where $$(r+I) \in R/I$$ $$r' \in R$$ and $q$ is the surjection onto the quotient module $R/I$, i.e. $$q:R \to R/I$$ explicitly defined by $$r \mapsto r+I?$$